# Porting this C++ float array to C#

Tags: c#, c++, translation

How would you port the down below C++ code to c#?

I have been using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]` for one dimensional float arrays that have a size const of 1 but I reached this 2 dimensional float array and I have no idea how to port it.

`typedef float TWAV32FS[1][2];`

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419367/pinvoke-marshalling-of-2d-multidimensional-array-of-type-double-as-input-and-out   And this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327196/marshalling-c-sharp-jagged-array-to-c

Comment: SizeConst = 1 are pretty weird arrays.  It almost certainly isn't, you probably found this at the end of a struct.  Where the actual size of the array is determined by a malloc() call in the client code.  And in this case is a blob of stereo sound data, just an array of structs.  Too much guessing.